# Turning characters into expression

Tags: r

I have several numeric variables in my testData:

```
testData<-data.frame(a1=1:10, a2=2:11, b1=101:110, b2=102:111)
```

I am pulling the names of the variables as below:

```
a<-names(select(test, starts_with("a")))
b<-names(select(test, starts_with("b")))
```

Then I am creating the combination of the following:

```
vardata<-expand.grid(a, b)   
vars<-paste(vardata$Var1,vardata$Var2,"=",vardata$Var1,"-",vardata$Var2)   
vars<-gsub("\\s+|\\s+?", "", vars)
```

If you run vars you should get:

```
"a1b1=a1-b1" "a2b1=a2-b1" "a1b2=a1-b2" "a2b2=a2-b2"
```

Now when pass it on to DPLYR mutate function, i get an error:

```
testData2<-mutate(testData, parse(text=vars))    

Error: unsupported type for column 'parse(text = vars)' (EXPRSXP, classes = expression)
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `=`  in a call (tagging) is not the same as `=` in an expression (assignment). You could build up an appropriate call to `mutate` this way, although it's a bit uglier:

```
> C <- call("mutate", quote(testData))
> for(e in parse(text=vars)) {C[as.character(e[[2]])] <-  e[3]; print(C) }
mutate(testData, a1b1 = a1 - b1)
mutate(testData, a1b1 = a1 - b1, a2b1 = a2 - b1)
mutate(testData, a1b1 = a1 - b1, a2b1 = a2 - b1, a1b2 = a1 -
    b2)
mutate(testData, a1b1 = a1 - b1, a2b1 = a2 - b1, a1b2 = a1 -
    b2, a2b2 = a2 - b2)
```

and then:

```
>eval(C)
   a1 a2  b1  b2 a1b1 a2b1 a1b2 a2b2
1   1  2 101 102 -100  -99 -101 -100
2   2  3 102 103 -100  -99 -101 -100
3   3  4 103 104 -100  -99 -101 -100
4   4  5 104 105 -100  -99 -101 -100
5   5  6 105 106 -100  -99 -101 -100
6   6  7 106 107 -100  -99 -101 -100
7   7  8 107 108 -100  -99 -101 -100
8   8  9 108 109 -100  -99 -101 -100
9   9 10 109 110 -100  -99 -101 -100
10 10 11 110 111 -100  -99 -101 -100
```

That said, there are much easier ways of generating linear combinations of columns.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I am actually looking an easy way of generating linear combinations as you mentioned. So it doesn't have to be done via mutate function. Anything you can propose would be great. 
Thanks